# Bitmap drawn using Open GL has a black square and color overlay (Android)

Tags: android, bitmap, opengl-es

Following is my Sprite code. The image drawn using this code has a black background (which covers the transparent background) and has a color overlay making the image look distorted.

How can I improve transparent image drawing on open gl es.

```
class Ship {
public int life = 5;

public FloatBuffer ShipVertexBuffer;
public FloatBuffer ShipTextureBuffer;
public PieceCluster cluster;

//! TEXTURES
private int[] textures = new int[1];
//! TEXTURES

public float ShipVerticles[] = {
        0, 0,       // лево низ
        0, 30,      // лево вверх
        30, 0,      // право низ
        30, 30      // право вверх
};

//! TEXTURES
public float ShipTextures[] = {
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f
};
//! TEXTURES

public Ship(PieceCluster c) {
    //! Буффер вертексов
    cluster = c;
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(36);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    ShipVertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    ShipVertexBuffer.put(ShipVerticles);
    ShipVertexBuffer.position(0);

    //! TEXTURES
    bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ShipTextures.length * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    ShipTextureBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    ShipTextureBuffer.put(ShipTextures);
    ShipTextureBuffer.position(0);
    //! TEXTURES
}

public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl) {
    // loading texture
    // generate one texture pointer

    Bitmap bitmap = cluster.Picture;
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    // ...and bind it to our array
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    // create nearest filtered texture
   // gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
  // gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    // Use Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap

    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    // Clean up
    bitmap.recycle();
}

public void draw(GL10 gl, float x, float y) {
    //! TEXTURE
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    //! TEXTURE

    gl.glColor4f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glTranslatef(x, y, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, ShipVertexBuffer);

    //! TEXTURE
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, ShipTextureBuffer);
    //! TEXTURE

    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    //! TEXTURE
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    //! TEXTURE
}
```

Comment: Russian comments, чувак. There would better to replace them by english version. Just for `StackOverflow`. :)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you've enabled blending.

Try adding `glEnable(GL_BLEND)` before your draw call. Use `glBlendFunc()` and `glBlendEquation()` to change the blending style to suit what effect you want.